# Duplicate class org.apache.http.HttpHeaders found in modules

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After updating my Android Studio to 3.5 version. I'm getting error this error:

```
Duplicate class org.apache.http.Consts found in modules
        httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar
        (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1) and
        httpcore-4.3.2.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
        Duplicate class org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException found in
modules httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar
        (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1) and
        httpcore-4.3.2.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
        Duplicate class org.apache.http.HttpConnectionFactory found in modules
        httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar
        (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1) and
        httpcore-4.3.2.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
        Duplicate class org.apache.http.HttpHeaders found in modules
        httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar
        (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1) and
        httpcore-4.3.2.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
        Duplicate class org.apache.http.MessageConstraintException found in
modules httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar
        (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1) and
        httpcore-4.3.2.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
        Duplicate class org.apache.http.TruncatedChunkException found in
modules httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar
        (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1) and
        httpcore-4.3.2.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
        Duplicate class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy found in modules
        httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar
        (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1) and
        httpcore-4.3.2.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
        Duplicate class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable found in modules
        httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar
        (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1) and
        httpcore-4.3.2.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
```

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Resolved by excluding the duplicates from the implemented libraries in your gradle file:

```
implementation ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.http'
}

implementation ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.http'
}
```

If you require more help post your gradle file in its entirety.

Comment: After adding I'm getting the following error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig; Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Probably notice probably
You have several identical libraries and delete similar libraries

But for you, you have to test different versions of httpclient